# Сложение + присоединение (PHP) - какая-то неразбериха!

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.
Вот ни как не могу понять PHP программирование в разрезе математики+логики, сложения и присоединения.
пример - [**тут**](http://icar-soft.ru/development/simple_math.php).
Объясните, как это получается и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Это же основы. В отличии от Делфи, в пхп есть оператор сложения, а есть оператор конкатенации строк.

Так вот. Если используется оператор сложения (плюс), то он преобразовывает свои аргументы в числа, а потом складывает. Оператор конкатенации (точка) делает это со строками.  Если аргумент число - он преобразует его предварительно в строку.

Так как преобразование строка-> число не всегда возможно, то и получаются самые различные артефакты.

Если из приведенных примеров на картинке какой то конкретный непонятен, копируйте его сюда, разберем.

p.s. никогда больше не давайте php текст картинкой!